# Angular 2 : export component on a module and import and use it inside a module

Tags: angular, typescript, module, components

I have a feature module called CustomerInfoModule which exports a CustomerInfoComponent. see below.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {RouterModule}  from '@angular/router'

import {CustomerInfoComponent} from './customer-info.component'

@NgModule({
declarations:[CustomerInfoComponent],
exports:[CustomerInfoComponent]
})
export class CustomerInfoModule{
}
```

I want to import and use this CustomerInfoComponent inside MissedCollectionsComponent. I am getting typescript error

> '.module"' has no exported member 'CustomerInfoComponent'

.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router'

import {MissedCollectionsComponent} from './missed-collections.component'

import {CustomerInfoComponent} from '../shared/customer/customer-info.module'

@NgModule({
imports:[RouterModule.forChild([
        {path:'missedcollection',component:MissedCollectionsComponent},
        {path:'missedcollection/customerinfo',component:CustomerInfoComponent}
    ]),
    CustomerInfoModule],
declarations:[],
exports:[]
})
export class MissedCollectionsModule{

}
```

As per the Angular2 documentation it says:

> 'We export the ContactComponent so other modules that import the
>   ContactModule can include it in their component templates.' [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)

Is it not logical to import componets from a module and use it inside another module. Am I wrong thinking that/or missing someting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you import from module file, you could do something like this.

customer-info.module.ts

```
import {CustomerInfoComponent} from './customer-info.component';
export {CustomerInfoComponent};
```

Comment: Yes that would work. Thanks. But my concern is when we export a component why its not visible to import from a another module.

Comment: @PrabashB note that, `exports` in NgModule mean, you do not need `declarations` some Components, Directives, Pipes if you `imports` other NgModule already `declarations` them.

Comment: thanks. it worked. small correction to your code. Below code worked for me.import {CustomerInfoComponent} from './customer-info.component'
export {CustomerInfoComponent} Please edit your code. so then I will accept it .

Comment: I want to make my CustomerInfoComponent encapsulated in the CustomerInfoModule. Therefore second option of importing file component directly would not be accepted as the anwer here.

Comment: A more complete answer would be much better here. Offering a 2-line code snippet with no real explanation isn't particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I understand Prabash B wants to make "*CustomerInfoComponent encapsulated in the CustomerInfoModule*" (as stated in one of his responses to the 1st answer), and therefore does not want to import the file component directly in `MissingCollectionsModule`.

However, there is a difference between Javascript Modules and NgModules as presented in the Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-vs-jsmodule.

The import statements at the top of the file are related to Javascript Modules, whereas the import, export, declarations and provider statements within the @NgModule decorator as related to NgModules.

Therefore it is perfectly fine to import the component directly in `MissingCollectionsModule`.