# Angular 6 with plain TypeScript - ERROR: module has no exported member

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have a small Angular 6 library in which I am building a reusable component to display page-level messages, such as error, info, warning, and success.

For this I have an enum `ServerMessageType.ts`, which is simple enough:

```
export enum ServerMessageType {
    Error = 'error',
    Info = 'info',
    Success = 'success',
    Warning = 'warning'
}
```

`ServerMessage.ts` should use `ServerMessageType`:

```
import { ServerMessageType } from './ServerMessageType';

export class ServerMessage {
    constructor(public type: ServerMessageType, 
                public messageText: string, 
                public dismissible?: boolean, 
                public id?: string) {
    }
}
```

`server-messages.component.ts`

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

import { ServerMessage } from './ServerMessage';
import { ServerMessageType } from './ServerMessageType';

    @Component({
  selector: 'app-server-messages',
  templateUrl: './server-messages.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class ServerMessagesComponent {

  @Input() messages: ServerMessage[];
  @Output() messageRemoved = new EventEmitter<ServerMessage>();

  constructor() {
  }

  clearMessage = function (index: number) {
    const message = this.messages[ index ];

    this.messageRemoved.emit(message);
    this.messages.splice(index, 1);
  };

  getMessageClass(message: ServerMessage): string {
    switch (message.type) {
      case ServerMessageType.Error:
        return 'alert-danger';
      case ServerMessageType.Info:
        return 'alert-info';
      case ServerMessageType.Success:
        return 'alert-success';
      case ServerMessageType.Warning:
        return 'alert-warning';
    }
  }

  isDismissible(message: ServerMessage): boolean {
    return message.dismissible === true;
  }
}
```

However, when I run `ng build`, I get an error:

```
BUILD ERROR  
> projects/framework/src/lib/server-messages/server-messages.component.ts(3,28):
> error TS2305: Module
> '"/Users/xxx/dev/apps/framework/projects/framework/src/lib/server-messages/ServerMessage"'
> has no exported member 'ServerMessageType'
```

What am I doing wrong? If I change `type` in `ServerMessage` to be a string and remove the `ServerMessageType` enum altogether, things build and deploy just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: what's in `./server-messages.component.html`?

Comment: Please check the `server-messages.component.ts`. You've wrong import statement.

Comment: @RitwickDey How? I must be blind.

Comment: You didn't share your `messages.component.ts`... You shared 'ServerMessageComponent.ts' .... Is this your mistake on stackoverflow?

Comment: @RitwickDey whoops, what I named ServerMessageComponent.ts is actually server-message-component.ts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 : export component on a module and import and use it inside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960959/angular-2-export-component-on-a-module-and-import-and-use-it-inside-a-module)

Comment: Nope. It is not duplicate. It is unrelated to Angular component or module. She is just using enum - language feature.

Comment: It is realy confusing. Can you tell me all the files name in `projects/framework/src/lib/server-messages/` @IsabellePlante

Comment: Are you using the `ServerMessageType` enum in your html temlplate at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake!

In **server-messages.component.ts**, these two lines:

```
import { ServerMessage } from './ServerMessage';
import { ServerMessageType } from './ServerMessageType';
```

Had been reverted to

```
import { ServerMessage, ServerMessageType } from './ServerMessage';
```

Thanks for your help! It couldn't find `ServerMessageType` in **ServerMessage.ts**, since it's exported in **ServerMessageType.ts**...

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to import your component in your root module and when you make service than make it @Injectable than use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly export a component from a module if you want to import that component by importing that module.

The code in which you must solve this problem is the module-code from which you want to export that component.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain a bit better with examples? I don't think I follow.

Comment: It is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960959/angular-2-export-component-on-a-module-and-import-and-use-it-inside-a-module?rq=1